# Easiest way to change namespace of VS2008 solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know a quick and foolproof way of changing the namespace of a VS2008 solution/projects?  In other words - I have a solution, and want to copy this as a template for a different application, but need different namespace obviously.

Thanks

Comment: The need to change namespaces is not obvious to me. That's why `using` statements for importing namespaces exist.

Comment: @oded: yes, but I have lots of boilerplate code that I want to reuse, but don't want to add to a class library.

Comment: that's why class libraries exist. Code reuse.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, I already use class libraries, but it does not make sense to put everything in them.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming Solution name will not affect namespace of projects in it.
 If you want to change namespace - right click project file -> select "properties" -> select "Application" tab -> Change "default namespace".

Only best fool proof way in my opinion

- Open solution in VS2008
- Open Solution Explorer
- Right Click Solution
- Select "Rename"

Comment: This will not help with all the files inside the solution that have a namespace that now needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the search & replace dialog:

Shift+Ctrl H

Find what: 
namespace YOUROLDNAMESPACE

Replace what:
namespace YOURNEWNAMESPACE

Look in:
Entire solution

Find options:

Tick Match case 
Tick Match whole word

Push button "Replace All"

HTH
Dimi

Comment: This is what I have done in the past, but it doesn't take into account file names, interproject references etc.  I wish VS would provide proper support for this!

Comment: Upthecreek, you just gave me an idea... If all your projects are in a source control... Then Dimi's method can work.

Just work in the source control rather than VS (just remember to start changing the sub project first and the main last + write on paper the names of the sub project so that you can test them... or at least understand what's wrong with them later if there are bugs)